# Real Analysis - convergence question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm working on the real analysis and I got stuck to this problem.

Could anyone please give me some help with this?

> Find all values of $p$ for which the series
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k}{\left(k^3-k\right)^p}$$
>   is convergent. Justify your answer.

Comment: Can you do it if the denominator is $(k^3)^p$? Would that make a substantial difference to $(k^3-k)^p$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k}{(k^3-k)^p}
&=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{k^{1-3p}}{(1-1/k^2)^p}
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\left(\frac34\right)^p\le(1-1/k^2)^p\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Letting $\displaystyle a_k = \frac{k}{(k^3 - k)^p}$ and $\displaystyle b_k = \frac{k}{(k^3)^p}$, show that $a_k/b_k \to 1$ as $k \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\frac k{(k^3-k)^p}=\frac1{k^{p-1}(k^2-1)^p}$$

So, for example:

$$p=1\implies\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac1{k^2-k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\left(\frac1{k-1}-\frac1k\right)=1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\ldots$$

$$p=\frac12\implies\sum_{k=2}^\infty\sqrt{\frac k{k^2-k}}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac 1{\sqrt{k-1}}\;\ldots$$

Can you see a pattern now (or perhaps do some more examples...)? And remember the [p-series test](http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/107/Series/INTTEST.HTM), of course.